# Using to_jsonb in LINQ

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I need to use the to_jsonb function in my LINQ. To get a code like this

```
SELECT ...
FROM Product AS a
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(to_jsonb(a), '$.* ? (@ like_regex "SOME TEXT")')
```

I haven't found anywhere how to use the to_jsonb function in EF CORE

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In the query given, you are attempting to filter on the entity you are querying in json format. Why do this? You should be able to simply add a `WHERE` to the given column that has the data you are looking for.

However, if this query is incorrect for some reason, try these:

See the Npgql docs [here](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/json.html#poco-mapping) for mapping a jsonb column to a POCO type. Then, you'll be able to write LINQ against it.

If you don't want to do that, you can use `RawSQL()`, see EF Core docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).